# PyQt5 issue with QApplication module

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have an issue where like many others i can't run some pyqt5 code because i get the error that vscode can't find the module QApplication when i run the command from pyqt5.QtWidgets import QApplication.
Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = uic.loadUi("interface.ui")
ui.show()

def recherche():
    if ui.NomProduit.text()!="":
        produit = str(ui.NomProduit.text())
    else:
        ui.NomProduit.setText("Veuillez rentrez le nom d'un produit")


ui.Recherche.clicked.connect(recherche)
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited `from PyQt5 import Uic` to `from PyQt5.uic import loadUi` and I used Opject Oriented Programing (OOP) . And I imported all methods `From PyQt5.QtWidgets import *`

Try this :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("interface.ui", self)
        self.show()
        self.Buttons()

    def Buttons(self):
         self.Recherche.clicked.connect(self.recherche)

    def recherche(self):
        if self.NomProduit.text()!="":
            produit = str(self.NomProduit.text())
        else:
            self.NomProduit.setText("Veuillez rentrez le nom d'un produit")

    

ui = Main()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: This is a good answer. However, you need to add a brief explanation of changes that you have made